# Get rid of all vowels at the end of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio-2010, replace

This is what I have:

```
word = Regex.Replace(word, @"[aeiouyAEIOUY]\z", String.Empty);
```

But I think this only gets rid of the last letter (if it's a vowel).

So `jrhyui` would return `jrhyu` whereas I really want to return `jrh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. `[aeiouyAEIOUY]` is a character class that matches exactly *one* vowel. You want to remove *all* the vowels from the end of the string, so match one or more instances of the character class. You can do this by appending a `+` at the end, like so:

```
[aeiouyAEIOUY]+\z
           // ^-- match any single character in the list one or more times
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qT5rE3)

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweak to your original code should do it:

```
word = Regex.Replace(word, @"[aeiouyAEIOUY]*\z", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will match your criteria: `(?i)[aeiou]+(?>$)(?-i)`